# iOS Programming: UITextField, listen for unfocus event

Tags: ios, ios4, uitextfield, lost-focus

How can I listen for unfocus event in UITextFiekd?

I would create a sort of handler that is activated when my text field lost the focus. For example, if I click into another part of the application, that listen registers the text inside the UITextField automatically.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [UITextFieldTextDidEndEditingNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006888-CH3-SW49) when the textfield resigns as first responder. You can also make use of the [delegate method textFieldDidEndEditing:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006991-CH3-SW7).

Answer (score 0):

You could add a custom notification to the default notification center singleton.

Start by setting up a method in your text fields superviews view controller that contains code that you want to be executed when your text field goes out of view:

```
-(void)textFieldLostFocus{
    //do some work here... 
}
```

Then add your notification observer to the default notification center. (u can put this in `viewDidLoad`)

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(textFieldLostFocus) 
                                                 name:@"TextFieldDidLoseFocus" object:nil];
```

And then inside the UITextfield's superviews view controller add this:

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"TextFieldDidLoseFocus" object:self userInfo:nil];
}
```

When the view goes out of view, your custom method will be called by the notification center.

Answer (score 0):

Two steps. First, define a delegate. Second, implement the `textFieldDidEndEditing:` delegate method. This selector is called when

> the text field resigns its first
>   responder status.

This is iOS-speak for losing focus. The documentation is [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextFieldDelegate).